# Como inserir um item de combobox no Banco SQL usando Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou com dificuldade de inserir um item da lista comboBox do Tkinter para o banco de dados SQL.
Apresenta o seguinte erro:

```py
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO listaMes (mes) values (?)""",(selecionarMes))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied.
```

Consigo printar o mês, mas não salvar no banco.

```py
root = Tk()
conn = sqlite3.connect('BancoCombo.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(""" 
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS listaMes(
                mes CHAR(15) NOT NULL
                );
                """)
conn.commit(); print('Banco Criado!')

def adicionar_combobox():
    
    selecionarMes = lista_meses.get(); print(selecionarMes)
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO listaMes (mes) values (?)""",(selecionarMes))
    

labelMes = Label(root,text='Selecione o Mês')
labelMes.pack()

meses = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro','Março']
lista_meses = ttk.Combobox(root,values=meses)
lista_meses.pack()
lista_meses.current(0)

btn_meses = Button(root,text='Enviar',command=adicionar_combobox)
btn_meses.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tente alterar o ```selecionarMes = lista_meses.get()``` para ```selecionarMes = [lista_meses.get()]``` e certifique de que seu cursor está dessa forma ```cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO listaMes (mes) values (?)""",selecionarMes)```

Comment: Então, ele não gera erro. Mas não grava. Abre um novo arquivo .db-journal. Fechando a execução ele some.
Obrigado !

Comment: Você está commitando após executar o cursor ?

Answer (score 0):

Segue o exemplo abaixo não é a melhor forma de se fazer, mais já vai te ajudar:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
 
def adicionar_combobox(mes):    
    print(mes)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('BancoCombo.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO listaMes (mes) values (?)""",[mes])
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()    

conn = sqlite3.connect('BancoCombo.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS listaMes( mes CHAR(15) NOT NULL ); """)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print('Banco Criado!')

root = tk.Tk()
labelMes = tk.Label(root,text='Selecione o Mês')
labelMes.pack()

meses = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro','Março']
lista_meses = ttk.Combobox(root,values=meses)
lista_meses.pack()

btn_meses = tk.Button(root,text='Enviar',command=lambda:adicionar_combobox(lista_meses.get()))
btn_meses.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Me ajudou muito, a sua primeira alternativa estava correta, esqueci de comitar depois do cursor do INSERT.

Comment: A segunda também funcionou.
Mais uma vez, Obrigado !